# Why can't I use lazy_split_view with a istream view instead of a string_view?

Tags: c++, istream, std-ranges, c++23, istream-iterator

Consider this code snippet (adapted from cppreference.com):

```
constexpr std::string_view text{"Hello-+-C++-+-23-+-!"};
constexpr std::string_view delim{"-+-"};
std::ranges::for_each(text | std::views::lazy_split(delim), act_on_substring);
```

I want to do the same for a stream - say, `std::cin` - instead of `text`. I've tried:

```
auto isv = std::views::istream<std::string>(std::cin);
constexpr std::string_view delim{"-+-"};
std::ranges::for_each(isv | std::views::lazy_split(delim), act_on_substring);
```

But [this code fails to compile](https://godbolt.org/z/5v5zYcxn6):

```
<source>:21:31: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('basic_istream_view<basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char>>, char, char_traits<char>>' and '_Partial<_LazySplit, decay_t<const basic_string_view<char, char_traits<char>> &>>' (aka '_Partial<std::ranges::views::_LazySplit, std::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char>>>'))
   21 |     std::ranges::for_each(isv | std::views::lazy_split(delim), act_on_substring);
      |                           ~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although `views::lazy_split` supports `input_range`, since the latter is a single-pass range, there is no way to go back to the previous element once iterated. In this case, the pattern range must be a [*`tiny-range`*](https://eel.is/c++draft/ranges#concept:tiny-range), which means its size must be smaller than or equal to 1.

The most you can do is:

```
std::ranges::for_each(
  std::views::istream<char>(std::cin) | std::views::lazy_split('+'),
  act_on_substring
);
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/83hW5bebx)

Comment: Actually, that's a good enough answer to merit rewriting the question to make it more specific to this example.

Comment: This makes me wonder. So okay, let's say I have an input range and I actually want to split it on `"-+-"sv`. The efficient way to do that would be to like allocate storage for 3 characters and then potentially push onto that - it's complicated but it could work, the upside being that you can really get a lazy split going. But the alternative is... what? Stick the entire input range into a `vector`?

Comment: Of course now suddenly we're bringing in `concat`-like semantics into here, so it's certainly not... easy.

Comment: @Barry: I was also wondering what the alternative is supposed to be. I wonder why the standard didn't just allow for this, where you could do the lazy split with a buffer you allocate of size at least as big as the delimiter.